# Visual studio 2008 stops responding frequently during edit and save

Tags: visual-studio-2008, performance

slow performance is the most annoying issue for me when using visual studio 2008 and happens very frequently. when I start writing the code and saving it, suddenly the visual studio becomes unresponsive and takes a while to come back. the time taken is lot more if I am editing an aspx mark-up page. I am not sure what processing is being done behind the scenes when I am writing the code, but this is affecting my day to day work. the solution I work with, has around 35 projects in it. it takes a long time to load and shut down. it is also very slow when I am simply opening an aspx file from the solution explorer (sometimes I get a message box saying "processing requests from background thread" and it closes after sometime). is there anything I can do to speed up visual studio? I am not much worried about slow loading and closing of the solution, but once it is loaded, it should be fast enough to work with. I use resharper 4.5 add-in and my PC has 2GB RAM. I applied the settings suggested in the link, but not much improvement. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440/visual-studio-optimizations. thanks for your help.

Comment: This question is not programming related and should probably be asked on superuser instead.

Comment: What is the maximum number of recommended projects per solution?  35 seems like a lot.